# libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory DREAMHOST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2, dreamhost

I have a RoR app deployed on DREAMHOST. Here are the versions that am currently running on

- Ruby: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails: Rails 3.2.3

The error when i try to load home page is as below:

```
libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/config/application.rb:7 
/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
/config/environment.rb:2
config.ru:3:in `require'
config.ru:3
```

I have tried updating the mysql2 gem, uninstalled and re-installed completed `bundle install` which was a success. I have tried  `wget -O` and added the file. But the error still persists. 
I have tried to search for answers but have not had much luck.

This is for production environment. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to gems. `libmysqlclient_r` complains that `mysql2.so` cannot be found because it's missing on your machine. You need to deal with it not using `bundler`, but rather by your system package manager (i.e. for Debian you can use `apt-get` or `aptitude`).

First, locate the absolute path of yout libmysqlclient_r.so:

```
dpkg -S libmysqlclient_r.so.16
```

now you've got the absolute path, so run:

```
ldd ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB/libmysqlclient_r.so
```

`ldd` lists the dependencies of given library. There will be at least one file missing. Now all you have to do is to install package(s) that are missing.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.dpkg command returns "no path matching pattern" result. However dpkg -S libmysqlclient_r.so lists 3 paths

Comment: Yep, it should return something like `$ dpkg -S libmysqlclient_r.so
libmysqlclient-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient_r.so; ...`. First path is that one you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, i get linux-vdso.so.1, libz.so.1, .... In dreamhost servers we wont be able to use apt-get. Is there any other way to go about this?